# odoo psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column res_partner.field_name does not exist

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, odoo-13

I am working with Jenkins pipeline. Odoo 13 is running on the production server.

When I start a build (script upgrade) to get production DB and upgrade it.

I have an error

**"psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column res_partner.field_name does not exist"**

Just after odoo.modules.loading: Modules loaded. and before the upgrade begins
I saw this solution:

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/odoo-13-error-when-adding-a-field-in-res-partner-175628

But I can't do that because as I said I am working with `Jenkins pipeline` I can't manipulate the server by the terminal.

I have this problem only when I want to add a field to the `res_partner` model ...

Answer (score 0):

upgrade the module where you are inheriting the res.partner and adding the new field "field_name". May be this will resolve your issue.